# Script to compare and delete the files based on name and extension type

Tags: linux, scripting, filenames, delete

My program creates two files with same name but different extension (for ex: 20162012.dat & 20162012.cnf). Sometimes the program fails to create .dat file.
So the other .cnf file becomes orphan. 
I am looking for a script to compare this and delete the orphan .cnf file for which its partner .dat file is not present.

Any scripts and suggestions.. please help.

I tried below one but errors out.. may be I am missing something. please correct.

Script:

```
for f in *.cnf
do
    [ -e "$f" ] || continue
    f="${f%%.cnf}"
    [ -e "$f".dat ] || rm -i -- "$f".cut
done
```

Error:

```
rm: cannot remove `20162010.cut': No such file or directory
```

Note: I am having the script and file to be compared and deleted in the same folder.

Thanks !

Comment: If `something.cnf` exists and `something.dat` doesn't, you try to `rm something.cut` which is not the same as `something.cnf`.

Answer (score 1):

Do:

```
for f in *.cnf; do [[ -f ${f%.*}.dat ]] || echo "$f"; done
```

This is a dry-run; replace `echo` with `rm` for actual action.

- `for f in *.cnf` iterates over the `.cnf` files
- `[[ -f ${f%.*}.dat ]]` checks if the relevant `.dat` file exists
- If not (`||`) then print (or remove) the file

Comment: Thank you ! I found this already on other thread and completed. Thanks.